# Distinct не работает с list

Tags: sql, запрос, firebird, interbase

У меня есть такое «view», с агрегатными функциями:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW STATISTIC_CONTRACT(
    PROPOSAL_ID,
    SORT_WORK_LIST,
    COUNT_SORT_WORK,
    DEPARTMENT_EXECUTE_LIST,
    COUNT_DEPARTMENT_EXECUTE)
AS
select d.PROPOSAL_ID,
list(distinct(sw.NAME_SORT_WORK), ', ') as SORT_WORK_LIST,
count(distinct(sw.NAME_SORT_WORK)) as COUNT_SORT_WORK,
list(distinct(dp.NAME_SHORT), ', ') as DEPARTMENT_EXECUTE,
count(distinct(c.DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE)) as COUNT_DEPARTMENT_EXECUTE
from DEVICES d
join SORT_WORK sw on d.SORT_WORK_ID = sw.ID
join CONTRACT c on c.PROPOSAL_ID = d.PROPOSAL_ID and c.DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE <> 13
join DEPARTMENT dp on dp.ID = c.DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE
group by d.PROPOSAL_ID
;
```

Результатом которого в «*SORT_WORK_LIST*», является **несколько** строк с **одинаковыми** значениями «*покраска, побелка*».

Вопрос: почему на этот результат *view* не работает запрос

> select distinct SORT_WORK_LIST from STATISTIC_CONTRACT where
>   SORT_WORK_LIST <> 'null'

т.е. результатом является теже несколько строк с одинаковыми значениями «*покраска, побелка*».

И как мне ограничить этот результат?
заранее спасибо

Comment: Согласно документации метода List, она принимает в качестве необязательного параметра ALL или DISTINCT. По умолчанию используется ALL. http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=list

Comment: Так я ж делаю второй *distinct*, уже после *all*? Т.е из результата, когда *list* уже выполнился

Comment: Проверьте, действительно ли дублирующиеся строки (покраска, побелка) совпадают. Возможно в дубликаты закрались латинские символы, например, "o" вместо "о"

Comment: поле "SORT_WORK_LIST" - в случае применения *list* (в *view*) оказывается типом "BLOB", так что уж тут поделать ничего наверное нельзя